# how to plot X-axis with long Strings in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

when I tried to plot some X-axis variables with long strings I got this result , I thought if I could put it on it's side it could better but I didn't knew how . I will be
thankful if you help me with better solution    [image]

Comment: So you're looking for a way to set the `rotation` of the `xticks`, perhaps using something like `plt.xticks(rotation = 45`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is : First as Grismar said in the comments use plt.xticks(rotation='vertical' or the number of the angle you want) , then go to "configure subplots"(as it shows in the picture below) in the bottom of plot window try to adjust it to look good , and then take the numbers of bottom and top and left and right and put it in code with plt.subplots_adjust() example:plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.476,left=0.057,right=0.917,top=0.9).
here is the documentation about [subplots_adjust](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html)
and documentation about [plt.xticks()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html#) and some [examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/matplotlib-pyplot-xticks-in-python/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ...or you could just use `layout='constrained'` and let the computer figure out the subplot size.